# javascript получить GET параметр

Tags: javascript, get

Нужно получить из урл значение get параметра "data", каким образом это можно реализовать?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Свойство [`window.location`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/location) содержит [объект](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location) со свойством `search` – строка, начиная со знака вопроса.

Напр., адрес `https://site.com/script?param=val&data=ololo` и JS код:

```
var strGET = window.location.search.replace( '?', ''); 
// в переменной strGET будет строка "param=val&data=ololo"
```

Дальше разбить по символу `&` и по знакам `=`.

Также пригодится ф-я [`decodeURIComponent()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/decodeURIComponent) для декодирования из urlencode значения параметра.

Полное решение по получению всех GET-параметров в JavaScript может быть таким:

```
var params = window
    .location
    .search
    .replace('?','')
    .split('&')
    .reduce(
        function(p,e){
            var a = e.split('=');
            p[ decodeURIComponent(a[0])] = decodeURIComponent(a[1]);
            return p;
        },
        {}
    );

console.log( params['data']);
// выведет в консоль значение  GET-параметра data
```

Comment: не работает в случае ?checkout=add&product[price][]=1220&product[title][]=jameson&product[price][]=2570&product[title][]=JackDanielli

Answer (score 6):

```
let params = (new URL(document.location)).searchParams; 
console.log(params.get("data"));
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Answer (score 2):

Если я правильно понял, что вы хотите сделать

```
var params = {};

if (window.location.href.match(/.*\?.*/)) {
  for (var i = 0; i < tmp_params.length; i++) {
    var _tmp = window.location.href.replace(/.*\?/,'')
      .split('&')[i]
      .split('=');

    params[_tmp[0]] = _tmp[1];
  }
}

alert(params.data);
```

Comment: installero,извините но ваш код не рабочий.

Answer (score 0):

```
const param = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search).get(
        "data"
      );
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]