# Как с помощью js получить данные из url?

Tags: javascript

Как из: https://www.site.com/name?v=M1hM67mxy8YWA

Как получить значение v=?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
var params = window
    .location
    .search
    .replace('?','')
    .split('&')
    .reduce(
        function(p,e){
            var a = e.split('=');
            p[ decodeURIComponent(a[0])] = decodeURIComponent(a[1]);
            return p;
        },
        {}
    );

console.log( params['v']);
```

[Источник](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/453355/javascript-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-get-%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%80)

Comment: Спасибо большое)