# Как передать тескт на другую страницу сайта через url?

Tags: php, html

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как передать  текст через ссылку url. Как передать текст,а потом отобразить на другой странице сайта.

```
<span>Товар 3245</span>
    <div><a href="form.html" class="btn-inner" target="_self">
    <button class="btn font-header" id="uid47" data-id="" data-action="link"  data-ga_category="" data-ga_action="" need_hover="true">
`<span class="text">КУПИТЬ</span>`</button>
                                                                                                </a></div>
```

Как передать вместе с ссылкой form.html название товара?

Comment: опишите подробнее ваш вопрос

Comment: А начало ссылки где? Потерялося?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

В общем виде URL имеет такую структуру: `<схема>:[//[<логин>[:<пароль>]@]<хост>[:<порт>]][/<путь>][?<параметры>][#<якорь>]`

Если `<схема>` - http или https, то `<логин>`, `<пароль>` и `<порт>` как правило не указываются.

Остается `http:[//<хост>[/<путь>][?<параметры>][#<якорь>]`.

Все, что вас интересует находится в блоке `<параметры>` - это список пар `Имя=Значение` разделенных символом `&`.

Для автоматического формирования параметров в HTML предусмотрен специальный тег [`<form>`](http://htmlbook.ru/html/form). Значения всех полей ввода автоматически передаются как параметры при нажатии на кнопку "submit" внутри тега `<form>`.

Обработкой параметров, как правило, занимается сервер. Но можно реализовать и на JavaScript. Примеры можно найти даже на SO, например, [javascript получить GET параметр](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/453355/javascript-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-get-%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%80)

Answer (score 4):

Не особо понятно, что именно Вы имели ввиду. Но, если я правильно понял, то можно передать через GET запрос.

Допустим:

```
http://site.ru/test.html?text=hello
```

На странице test.html:

```
<html>
Вы прислали: <b><? echo $_GET["text"]?></b>
</html>
```

На сервере должна быть включена обработка php в html файлах.

Comment: спасибо, а это значение можно присвоить переменной?

Comment: Можно. `<? $i = $_GET["text"]; ?>`. $i - переменная.