# Значение input в зависимости от url с которого перешли на страницу

Tags: javascript, html

Такая ситуация, есть страница с таким слайдером:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
  <li><a href="/price/3D-visualized.html">3D ВИЗУАЛИЗАЦИЯ</a></li>
  <li><a href="/price/VKR.html">ВКР</a></li>
  <li><a href="/price/interior-design.html">ДИЗАЙН ИНТЕРЬЕРА</a></li>
    ...
```

Ссылки ведут на отдельные страницы с услугами на (этом же сайте, ***сайт статичный***).

Вопрос, как лучше вставить значение имени *(например:3D ВИЗУАЛИЗАЦИЯ)* в `<input>` на **отдельной странице с формой**, если переход на нее был осуществлен с конкретной страницы с услугой?

Как это сделать, по возможности **без использования POST/GET** запросов? Можно на словах или ссылку на пример реализации.

Можно конечно каждый раз узнавать url и написать кучу `if` , но как это сделать нормально?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [javascript получить GET параметр](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/453355/javascript-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%83%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-get-%d0%bf%d0%b0%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%82%d1%80)

Comment: @AlexDevTime нет мне просто нужны варианты как это лучше сделать

Answer (score 1):

Получилось сделать так, но хотелось бы увидеть ещё варианты:

- на странице с услугой *(html для примера структуры)*:

```js
let selector = 'a[href$="order.html"]';
let links = document.querySelectorAll(selector);
/*выделяем ссылки
содержащие 'order.html' , ведущие на страницу с <input>*/

for (var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) { 
  links[i].setAttribute("onclick", "return false");
}//отключаем переход по всем ссылкам на страницу с <input>

[].forEach.call(links, function(links) {

  links.addEventListener('click', function() {
    /*устанавливаем обработчик событий клика
     на ссылки, ведущие на страницу с <input>*/

    let locname = document.querySelector('a[href="' + new URL(window.location).pathname + ".html".toString() + '"]').innerHTML;
    /*получаем url текущей страницы
с услугой(https://site.ru/price/3D-visualized.html)
отделяем директорию с помощью
pathname (/price/3D-visualized), затем
по атрибуту href="/price/3D-visualized.html" 
получаем значение содержимого тега <a>...<a>*/

    let url = new URL('https://site.ru/to-order'); //url страницы с <input>

    url.searchParams.set('name', locname) //вставляем в url параметр search(?name=3D ВИЗУАЛИЗАЦИЯ)

    document.location.href = encodeURI(url);
    /*кодируем латиницу и пробелы
        и осуществляем переход по ссылке*/

  }, false);
});
```

```html
<nav id="menu" class="menu">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a href="/index.html">ARCHSUPPORT</a>
    </li>

    <li>
      <a href="/to-order.html">ЗАКАЗАТЬ</a>
    </li>
    ....

  </ul>
</nav>

....

<a class="a-active" href="/price/3D-visualized.html">3D ВИЗУАЛИЗАЦИЯ</a>
<a href="/price/VKR.html">ВКР</a>
<a href="/price/interior-design.html">ДИЗАЙН ИНТЕРЬЕРА</a> ....

<div class="txtcontent">
  <p>Чтобы узнать точную цену и сроки выполнения проекта <a href="/to-order.html">напишите нам.</a></p>

</div>
```

- на странице с `<input>` такой скрипт:

```js
function urls() {

  let input = document.querySelector('input[name="a_subject"]');

  let url = decodeURIComponent(decodeURIComponent(new URL(window.parent.location).search)).replace(/[^0-9A-ZА-Яа-яЁё]/g, " ").replace(/^\s*/, '')
  /*получаем url текущей страницы(parent.location если форма в <iframe>)
  декодируем url/убираем лишние символы из строки */

  input.value = url;

}

urls()
```

Comment: Это было бы легче на php в 5 раз сделать с помощью GET, который на странице на которую перешли можно просто получить из супер-глобального массива $_GET

Comment: @МихаилКамахин сомневаюсь что проще, нужно каждый раз посылать запрос на сервер за какой-то ссылкой

Comment: Запросы будут происходить каждый раз, если ваш сайт динамичный

Comment: @МихаилКамахин он статичный

Comment: Чтобы люди им пользовались, его придётся делать на php(это легко), либо как вы крутиться на JavaScript, что весьма неудобно. Можно сделать сайт и на python и на node.js, но на php это всё быстро

Comment: @МихаилКамахин о чем вы , наличие php скрипта разве делает его динамичным? для валидации и отправки  форма я его использую, разумеется

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/103094/discussion-between---and--).

Answer (score 1):

Файл `file.php` находится в корне сайта
Это просто пример, этот файл можно в любое место положить

```html
<a href="/file.php?name=superValue"></a>
```

Файл `file.php`:

```php
<?php
    $romanValue = $_GET['name'];
    echo $romanValue;
?>
```

Таким образом выведется то, что было написано в `name=`
В данном случае я написал `name`, но вместо можно придумать абсолютно любое слово

Comment: А если ?name нет изначально