# Нужно из URL забрать значение одного параметра и передать в скрипт

Tags: javascript, html

Есть ссылка http://max.ru/index.html?test=123321&set=43234

Нужно забрать значение параметра test

и вставить в скрипт, вместо **"СЮДА"**

```
img height="1" width="1" style="display:none" src="https://www.ilonmask.com/tr?id=СЮДА&ev=PageView&noscript=1"/>
```

Comment: С помощью js формировать <noscript> - сомнительная идея.

Comment: Выбора нет( Есть ноускрипт и в него нужно вставить переменную из значения параметра url((

Comment: А к бэкэнду доступ есть? Это же GET-запрос. Можно переменную перехватить, которой присваивается $GET_['test'].

Comment: Увы, нет( это всё делается на конструкторе, без возможности использовать php и сессии

Comment: Это не будет работать.

Comment: Хорошее решение: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/453360/331312

Answer (score 0):

Как то так:

```
(function (tag, id) {
  if (id) {
      id = id.match(/test=(.+)&?/i);
      if (id != null && id.length > 0) {
        tag.textContent = tag.textContent.replace('{id}', id[1]);
      }
  }
}(document.querySelector('noscript'), location.search));
```

Comment: Код, который я приложил это носкрипт, я просто не стал его заключать в скобки

Comment: Ясно, получается вы не можете заменить именно данные в теге носкрипт ? минуту, поправлю ответ

Comment: http://joxi.ru/12M8weVTkMPewm Вот тут полный код, куда нужно вставить переменную из Url (отметил стрелочками)

Answer (score 0):

Получить значение параметра test из адресной строки можно ещё так:

```js
var params = location.search.substring(1).split("&");
var result;
for(i = 0; i < params.length; i ++){
    if (params[i].split("=")[0] == "test"){
        result = params[i].split("=")[1];
        break;
    }
}
alert(result);
```

Но Вы не можете программно вставить это значение в качестве параметра для элемента, находящегося между открывающим и закрывающим тегами noscript, так как всё, что там находится, программно недоступно. А вот в полном коде 9 строку можно будет переписать так: fbg('init', 'result');